# Button in MudBlazor table not routing to different page

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I’m new with both Blazor and MudBlazor. I was following along with a video on MudBlazor and I like how it can quickly have both filtering and sorting. However, now I’m trying to have some buttons for in the table row for CRUD operations on a record. I can’t seem to get it to route to another page nor have a been able to find a way to pass the record ID to a function. I’ve tried both a MudButton and a Bootstrap button and can’t get either to work.

In the code below I have a button that I would like to a different page as well as an Edit button I would like to navigate to another page while passing along the record ID. When I run this and try to go to the Groups button nothing happens. No errors, just not routing to another page.

Anyone know what I’m missing or maybe a example I can follow?

```
<MudTable Items="@listApplications" Dense="true" Hover="true" Bordered="true" Striped="true" 
        Filter="new Func<Application,bool>(FilterFunc1)" @bind-SelectedItem="selectedApplication">
        <ToolBarContent>
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
        </ToolBarContent>
        <HeaderContent>
            <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
            <MudTh>Description</MudTh>
            <MudTh></MudTh>
        </HeaderContent>
        <RowTemplate>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Description">@context.Description</MudTd>
            <MudTd>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="GoToGroups()">Groups</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >
                    Edit
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
            </MudTd>
        </RowTemplate>
        <PagerContent>
            <MudTablePager />
        </PagerContent>
    </MudTable>

@code {
    private List<Application>? listApplications;

    private string searchString = "";
    private Application selectedApplication = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        listApplications = await _db.GetApplications();
    }

    private bool FilterFunc1(Application app) => FilterFunc(app, searchString);

    private bool FilterFunc(Application app, string searchString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
            return true;
        if (app.Description.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;
        if (app.Name.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        return false;
    }



    void ShowApplication(int id)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"ApplicationMgmt/{id}");
    }

    void CreateNewApplication()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("ApplicationMgmt");
    }

    void GoToGroups()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Groups");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blazor you specify an event handler using the syntax `@on{DOM EVENT}="{DELEGATE}"`.

So you need to use `@onclick="GoToGroups"` instead of `onclick="GoToGroups()"`.

[Blazor event handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

To pass parameters you can use this syntax: `@onclick="() => ShowApplication(100)"`. So for your example:

```
<RowTemplate>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Description">@context.Description</MudTd>
    <MudTd>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" @onclick="GoToGroups">Groups</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @onclick="() => ShowApplication(context.Id)">
            Edit
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
    </MudTd>
</RowTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried removing the "()" before and it didn't do anything. Now I see that I have an error when I look at the browser dev tools. "Uncaught ReferenceError: GoToGroups is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick". I'll have to go see what I can find about that error. It might have to do with using a regular button inside a MudTable?

Comment: You also have to add the `@` character at the start. You have to use `@onclick` instead of `onclick`.

Comment: Thanks! I did have to ad the "@" and that worked. Now I just need to figure out how to pass an ID. I'll look back over some of the Blazor examples on that and hopefully figure that one out.

Comment: Edited my answer to include solution for passing the id parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it worked. I swear I had tried that before and got an error. Could have been the same thing where I left off my "@" for the onclick event. Either way that looks like it got me going again. Thanks!